# How can I make a jquery vertical timed content slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to make a vertical jquery timed content slider. I have five sections, each with their own ID and class of 'section' within a div with a class of 'holder'. I have this js code so far, but all the sections seem to be sliding up at once, and I'm getting an error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4, #section5').hide('fast');

});

$('.holder #section1').show('slow').delay(3000);
$(this).slideUp('fast');
$(this).nextUntil(['#section5']).show('slow').delay(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this very simple timed slideshow below! I love it!

```js
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      3000);
});
```

```css
fadein { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadein">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>
```